# TypeError: function missing 1 possitional argument "s"

Tags: python, funcion

Intenté llamar la función y me salió el siguiente error:

> TypeError: function missing 1 possitional argument "s"

Código de la función.

```
s = str(input())
def funcion(self, s:str):
  n = s.upper
  return n
print(funcion(s))
```

¿Cómo podría llamar a esta función? ¿Qué otro parametro hay que pasarle?

Comment: Quita el `self` de tu definición de función. Ese parámetro se usa cuando la función es parte de una clase (y entonces se denomina _metodo_ en vez de funcion) y no es tu caso

Comment: Por otro lado, si lo que quieres es devolver la cadena en mayúsculas, te ha faltado invocar `upper`. Poniendo sólo `s.upper` no se invoca, debes poner `s.upper()` (te faltaron los paréntesis)

Answer (score 2):

Sólo se usa el primer parámetro `self` cuando escribes **métodos** de una clase, en cualquier otro caso, se omite.

```
def funcion(s:str):
  n = s.upper()
  return n

s = input("?")
print(funcion(s))
```

Además te falta el `()` en la invocación al método `upper`.

(También es recomendable colocar un mensaje en el input para que el usuario sepa que necesita ingresar algo. Mejor todavía decirle que debe ingresar).